# Is it safe to take prescription drugs to Hungary?

Tags: legal, hungary, drugs

I am traveling to Budapest. I plan to bring a prescription drug, specifically bupropion (Wellbutrin). It's in the original container with my name on it, and also I have the official prescription receipt (from Canada).

I know the Hungarian authorities there are strict about illegal drugs and I'm slightly worried that bupropion could be illegal even with prescription in Hungary or something awful like that. Most government sites claim there are resources for checking this kind of thing, but in practice I have never found the information I needed.

Should I be worried about bringing bupropion with a prescription to Hungary?

Comment: I personally know a case where someone took just this medication to Hungary (in 2017), and nobody cared. Realistically, if you have a three-week supply in your luggage or carry-on, nobody will ever know even. If you plan to bring a five-year’s refill, that might be different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://www.drugs.com/international/bupropion.html lists two commercial names for bupropion in Hungary, `Elontril` and `Wellbutrin SR`, so it is safe to assume that the medication is not illegal.

Now, what is left is ensuring that you are allowed to import the pills. There are some questions in the site about this, but I cannot find nothing specific for Hungary. Googling a little provides http://gotohungary.com/entering-and-leaving-the-country which states:

> Medication: Tourists are permitted to bring medication for personal use. Products containing narcotic substances can only enter with the special permission of the Ministry of Health and Welfare.

From the description of Bupropion in the first link, I think it is safe to assume that it is not a narcotic.

In any case, get a copy of your doctor prescription in case you get asked about it.