# What medicines are allowed into Hungary from my list below?

Tags: hungary

I would like to know about medications that I take on a permanent basis and whether they are allowed to be brought into Budapest, Hungary.

I have a large amount of prescription only drugs that I take daily. Could you tell me if the following are allowed into Hungary to cover the days I will be holidaying there?

- Morphine sulphate/sevredol, pills needed: 28
- Diazapam, pills needed: 7
- Accrete, pills needed: 14
- Cetrizine, pills needed: 7
- Esomeprazole, pills needed: 7
- Estradot, pills needed: 2
- Ferous fumerate, pills needed: 14
- Folic acid, pills needed: 7
- Glucophage, pills needed: 14
- Humaline qwik pen, pens needed: 2
- Invega, tablets needed: 7
- Lamotigrine, tablets needed: 14
- Lamotigrine, tablets needed: 14
- Mirtazapine, tablets needed: 7
- Hypodermic insulin needles, needles needed: 14
- Naprozen, tablets needed: 14
- Pregabaline, tablets needed: 14
- Propranolol, tablets needed: 14
- Rifamaxin, tablets needed: 14

I will be bringing with me a prescription list as provided by my doctor. My pills are placed in a pill dispensing box once a week, so I do not need the boxes.

Is it alright just to bring the dispensing box and a repeat prescription list, rather than bringing each different medication in its original box?

Bringing each individual box would take an enormous amount of room, and leave little room in my hand baggage for anything else.

Comment: Now I need some analgesics for my poor ears.

Comment: In which country did you obtain the doctor's prescription?

Comment: For reference, writing in all capital/uppercase letters indicates shouting in internet communication.

Comment: Please make an effort to make a readable list.

Comment: Plan for a looooooong time at Customs.  Remembering Customs will be at the first airport you land inside the Schengen area, and anywhere else not in Schengen.  So if you go Mexico City - JFK - Heathrow - Warsaw - Hungary, you'll do customs at JFK, Heathrow and Warsaw.

Comment: If the pills are in blister packs in carboard boxes, you can bring the folded-down boxes with you, especially if that box has your prescription label on it.

Comment: @3kstc. Sometimes I wish we had a way to upvote particularly good edits.

Comment: Are you sure this is for one person? Not considering all the "useless stuff", and diabetes stuff... paliperidone plus lamotrigine, **plus** diazepam **plus** morphine... plus H1 blocker, plus beta blocker... most people would be unable to open an eye, let alone travel. Border patrol does not usually have a degree in pharmacology or any such thing, but I'd think this _will_ raise some concerns either way.

Comment: You appear to have duplicated "Lamotigrine" (or is this deliberate?).  You can [edit] the text to remove the duplicate.

Comment: @Harper, immigration will be at the first airport in the Schengen zone but customs will (mostly) be where you leave the airport, so not where you transit within Schengen.

Answer (score 22):

With respect to the other author, I'm not so sure this will be trouble-free.  We have [another question here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107319/is-it-safe-to-take-prescription-drugs-to-hungary) about taking prescription drugs to Hungary, which quotes an official source as saying

> Products containing narcotic substances can only enter with the special permission of the Ministry of Health and Welfare.

which would certainly include morphine, and quite possibly diazepam.  Although the site giving the original advice is down, and the replacement is much less helpful, I would never assume it'll be OK to cross a border with narcotics.  You should probably contact your local Hungarian embassy/consulate and get advice from the source, preferably in writing.

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR:**

Take your medication with the original box with the pills inside the sealed blister pack with doctors prescription. Get in touch with your nearest [Hungarian Embassy/Consulate](https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/country/hungary/) and cross check if these prescriptions are permissible into Hungary.

**Long version:**

If I were you I would take the medications with their original boxes and the pills/tablets in their sealed blister packs, alongside with your dispensing box.

Should Customs pull you aside with all these medicines, it is easier for the Customs officials to identify the medication by looking at the chemical ingredients on the box, rather than them looking at a pill and taking your word for what they are.

If these drugs are for legitimate use, you've got nothing to be scared for, and it is good to be prepared for the unforeseen, by having as much printed documentation on you to show officials when you arrive.

Furthermore it might be advisable to take a doctors prescription with you and let your doctor and pharmacist know you're travelling overseas, should the Customs officials want to cross check with your doctor/pharmacist.

With so many medicines, it might be advisable to get in touch with your nearest [Hungarian Embassy/Consulate](https://www.embassy-worldwide.com/country/hungary/), and go over your list of medication and ask if these are permissible to Hungary? If it is permissible, you should request to get a written document from them stating so.

Furthermore it might be good to have a record on when and who you spoke with at which Hungarian Embassy, should you have any problems while you're travelling.

Comment: If need be you can take a 2nd piece of hand baggage for your drugs, as a reasonable adjustment (at least on any European flight)

Comment: Just because it is legal to prescribe certain drugs in one country it does not follow that it is legal to bring in those drugs to a country where it might not be legal to prescribe the same drugs. Cannabis (even only cannabisoil pills) would be an example. To advice a person to just bring drugs across a border without checking the rules before travelling is bad advice.

Comment: @Bent thank you for your feedback, I've tried to improve my answer.

Comment: @Bent and could possibly lead to [death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_for_drug_trafficking) in some countries